# Why `system` is not hide by these obfuscator of PHP

Tags: php, obfuscation

I am recently trying to pick an obfuscator, I tried these I googled:

https://www.gaijin.at/en/tools/php-obfuscator
http://www.pipsomania.com/best_php_obfuscator.do
https://www.tools4nerds.com/online-tools/php-obfuscator

they are working well on obfuscating variable names and function names, but none of them can hide the function `system`, can anyone tell me why is that?

Comment: Incidentally, since this was originally posted on security.SE: Be aware that obfuscation is *NOT* security and does *NOT* make it safe to store secrets in source code. Anything that the computer can figure out - that is, any script or even binary it can execute - a human can figure out too. Obfuscation makes reading your script slower and more annoying, but it doesn't make it impossible, or even hard enough to dissuade more than the most casual reverse engineers. It also screams "I'm hiding something!" Any stored secret would certainly be found, and probably much faster than you expect.

Comment: Oh, also, using `system` is a terrible, terrible idea from a security perspective. It runs your command in a shell (`/bin/sh` or `cmd.exe`), instead of running it directly (which is still risky but much easier to do safely). Shells offer a plethora of ways to break out and execute arbitrary code. The vast majority of successful remote attacks yielding arbitrary code executions are probably shell escapes.

Answer (score 2):

Those tools are for making your code harder to understand by reducing its readability: they remove indentation and comments, replace meaningful names of your variables and [user-defined functions](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) and even encodes your string contents. The goal is to make it harder to modify or reuse your code, as PHP is an interpreted language, making the source code visible for the site/application administrators. **For this purpose there's no use in obfuscating PHP's [built-in functions](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/functions.internal.php)**, and you could see the same happening with e.g. `echo()`:

```
ORIGINAL:     echo "Obfuscated string.\n";
Gaijin.at:    echo base64_decode('T2JmdXNjYXRlZCBzdHJpbmcuCg==');
Tools4Nerds:  echo "O\x62f\x75s\x63a\x74\x65\x64 \x73t\x72\x69n\x67\x2e\n";
```

For obfuscating even the built-in function names, [`eval()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) is widely used for evil purposes. This way, the PHP source code can be handled as a string before execution, enabling every method used for string obfuscation.

```
ORIGINAL:     system('uptime');
OBFUSCATED:   eval(base64_decode("c3lzdGVtKCd1cHRpbWUnKTs="));
```

Even this example shows that obfuscation is not possible completely without the built-in functions. Encoding usually makes the source code longer, and the more you need to encode the slower the execution gets. Site administrators do care about the site performance and the extra resources consumed, but that doesn't bother criminals harnessing the server for their own use.